# Can't run Firefox on OSX

Tags: macos, firefox

Every page I go to **including the link from Firefox to upgrade Firefox**
shows this:

[image]

Clicking on advanced shows Mozilla is rejecting its own certificate which has not expired

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. This looks more like something suitable for superuser.com

Comment: That doesn't look like Mozilla's SSL cert though.

Comment: ok, I'll ask it in another forum, ty

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to close/delete this question.

Turns out I needed to export the ZScaler certificate from Chrome and then import it into Firefox and problem went away